# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser some pages issue

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a code for read all inputs in a form.

The code works in my demo page an others, but not work in some pages.
For the example issue:

facebook:

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com';

$html = file_get_html($url);
$post = $html->find('form[id=reg]'); //id for the register facebook page

print_r($post);
```

Print an empty array.

Functional example:

```
$url = 'http://www.monografias.com/usuario/registro';

$html = file_get_html($url);

$post = $html->find('form[name=myform]');
print_r($post);
```

Print a form content

Comment: Can you provide relevant html nodes?

Comment: I would love to get some control cases to look at specifically.  That way we are all looking at the same sets of data.

Comment: What nodes? I only need take the form content. The functional example works. why not in facebook for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook won't give you registration form directly, it will only respond with basic html, and the rest will be created with javascript. see for yourself

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com';
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

there is no form with "reg" ID in the html they send you.

Comment: Yes, is this. I'ts imposible in this case?. When any web charge the code with javasrcipt?

Comment: I'm afraid the only way is to use a headless browser like phantomjs.org, save the evaluated result and parse it, but I think that's way too complex for a task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

simple_html_dom.php contains a line limiting the max file size it will parse:

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

For files larger than this size, `file_get_html()` will just return `false`.